# CSS: Box should only have the width of the text without using <br>

Tags: css

Right now, I have an issue that I don't understand.

This is my code:

```css
.item {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.title_container {
  padding: 10px;
}

.title {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="title_container">
    <div class="title">
      Hello
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="title_container">
    <div class="title">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="title_container">
    <div class="title">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br> amet
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The result should like the third item. But it needs a `<br>` to have the width that is provided from the text width. Without a `<br>`, the grey box is wider than it's needed.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: you cannot do this

Comment: @TemaniAfif Oh, I didn't expect that. Is there a way to get the width of the longest line and then take this as width for the box, maybe with jQuery?